# I am using open-telemetry in go, how can I keep the tracerId of gin and grpc the same?

Tags: go, go-gin, open-telemetry, grpc-go

I am a go newbie, I am using [otelgin](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-go-contrib/tree/main/instrumentation/github.com/gin-gonic/gin/otelgin) and [otelgprc](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-go-contrib/tree/main/instrumentation/google.golang.org/grpc/otelgrpc) in open-telemetry/opentelemetry-go-contrib to track microservice links, currently my project uses gin for api-gateway and then gin routes in to call grpc services.

But I was never able to pass the tracerId from otelgin to otelgrpc, so two tracers are generated for one request.

If someone can help me with this problem it would be great, thanks.

[image]

I expect to be able to pass tracerId from gin to grpc, using only one tracerId, instead of generating two links.

If more information is needed, I can add it, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

In [otelgin middleware](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-go-contrib/tree/main/instrumentation/github.com/gin-gonic/gin/otelgin), the traceable context is propagated through `ginContext.Request.Context()`. So you can pass on this request context instead of ginContext to your gRPC client to propagate trace.

Answer (score 0):

as you said，you shoud do the fllowing.

1. Use c.Request.Context to pass to the rpc call function,like this

```
func grpcExample(c *gin.Context){
    example(c.Request.Context(), name)
}

func example(ctx context.Context, name string){
  greeterClient.SayHello(ctx, &helloworld.HelloRequest{Name: name})
}
```

2. greeterClient

```
credentials := []grpc.DialOption{
    grpc.WithTransportCredentials(insecure.NewCredentials()),           
    grpc.WithUnaryInterceptor(otelgrpc.UnaryClientInterceptor()),    
  grpc.WithStreamInterceptor(otelgrpc.StreamClientInterceptor()),
}
conn, err := grpc.Dial("grpcServerURI", credentials...)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
greeterClient = helloworld.NewGreeterClient(conn)
```

3. greeterServer

```
s := grpc.NewServer(
    grpc.UnaryInterceptor(otelgrpc.UnaryServerInterceptor()),
    grpc.StreamInterceptor(otelgrpc.StreamServerInterceptor()),
)
```

more deail: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-go-contrib/tree/main/instrumentation/google.golang.org/grpc/otelgrpc